# While condition not breaking

Tags: python, while-loop

Why while condition does not work for this case ?

```
 def Fibonacci():
    user = int( input("Type the length of Fibonacci numbers will be generated: ") )
    fbnc_list = [0, 1]
    
    _continue_ = True
    while _continue_:
      for n in range(0, user + 1):
        fbnc_list.append( fbnc_list[n] + fbnc_list[n + 1] )
        #print(fbnc_list, len(fbnc_list), user)
        if len(fbnc_list) == user: _continue_ = False

    return (fbnc_list)

Fibonacci()
```

On the comment line, i see that when i input 10 it should break on this case 
[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34] 10 10
len(fbnc_list) == user / 10 == 10.
 So _continue is set to False and while should stop.
Not what it's happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `_continue_` to `False` will stop the `while` loop at its next iteration, but it won't break out of the `for` loop.

If you want to immediately stop the loop, you'll need to unset `_continue_` *and* immediately break the `for` loop:

```
            if len(fbnc_list) >= user:
                _continue_ = False
                break
```

Note that you don't need two loops in the first place -- a single `for` loop with as many iterations as you need additional items (i.e. the amount of desired numbers minus the two you started with) will suffice:

```
def fibonacci(n):
    fibs = [0, 1]
    for _ in range(n - 2):
        fibs.append(fibs[-2] + fibs[-1])
    return fibs[:n]  # handles n < 2

print(fibonacci(int(input(
    "Type the number of Fibonacci numbers to generate: "
))))
```

```
Type the number of Fibonacci numbers to generate: 10
[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34]
```

Answer (score 0):

how about this?

```
def Fibonacci():
    user = int( input("Type the length of Fibonacci numbers will be generated: ") )
    fbnc_list = [0, 1]
    
    _continue_ = True
    while _continue_:
      for n in range(0, user + 1):
        fbnc_list.append( fbnc_list[n] + fbnc_list[n + 1] )
        #print(fbnc_list, len(fbnc_list), user)
        if len(fbnc_list) == user: _continue_ = False;break

    return (fbnc_list)

Fibonacci()
```

Comment: You could explain that how you solved this problem instead of "how about this?".

Comment: Nice trick with ';' . I'll use for now on

Comment: I would not strictly consider using the semicolon to write one line if statements good practice.